# How to set width of <div> to fit constant number of letters in monospace font?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I researched for a while, hasn't found a CSS solution yet, `em` and `ex` units are not correct in this case.  What I want is simply a div box that exactly fits 80x25 monospace text.  Do I have to resort to Javascript solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`em` does work in this case, if you know the proper ratios involved with your font. Try the following HTML:

(The danger with this is that some browsers adjust the font, which can alter the width/height of the font. For 100% accuracy, you might have to go with JavaScript.)

```
<style type="text/css">
    #text-container {
        border: #f00 solid 1px;
        font: 10px/1.2 Courier, monospace;
        width: 48em;  /* 80 x 0.6 (the width/height ratio of Courier) */
        height: 30em; /* 25 x 1.2 (line-height is 1.2) */
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>

<div id="text-container">
00000000001111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
</div>
```

Comment: What if the user have no Courier font? In this case monospace font may have a different width/height ratio. Even the ratio of the same font is not a constant at different scale, try zoom in/out the page.

Comment: Yup, as I wrote in my last paragraph this is not a perfect method, but it's the closest you will get using CSS. Courier has different ratios depending on its size, and on top of that some browsers adjust the font to "look better". Fonts have always been hard to measure and this case is not different. Basically, you're best off using JavaScript for this (let the browser render, then measure.)

Comment: That tiny last paragraph after a giant code block is so easy to be overlooked :)

Comment: If you don't hide a paragraph like that below a huge code block, you will of course get downvoted for saying it... ;P

Comment: When I try your code it gives me a box that is 60x25 characters. With the fallback monospace it gives a box that is 80x25...

Answer (score 33):

Try using the `ch` unit described [in the CSS3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#font-relative-lengths):

> Equal to the used advance measure of the "0" (ZERO, U+0030) glyph found in the font used to render it.

Thus `width: 80ch` specifies an 80 character width limit.

Comment: These days, assuming you don't have to support browsers older than IE9, this is the correct solution. The `ch` unit is a relatively new thing (there isn't even a caniuse matrix for it), which is why the older answer above is the accepted one.

Comment: I have to just add that `ch` still doesn't work properly on IE11. I would love to be able to use it as it is exactly the solution required, but it simply doesn't work everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

For the height you can use `em`, but you have to set the `line-height` also:

```
height: 25em; line-height: 1em;
```

Or with a bit more spacing:

```
height: 30em; line-height: 1.2em;
```

There is no CSS unit for a character width, so there I am afraid that you need some Javascipt...

Comment: If you know the ratio of a character's height and width, you can set the proper width using ems (it only works with monospace fonts where each character has the same width, though).

Comment: Yes, that would work if you knew the ratio, but you never do. The ratio varies with the actual font used, and how the text is rendered (font smoothing, et.c.).

Comment: *Do* you have to know the ratio? I thought `em`, `ex`, and `ch` were interpreted as character heights when used for height properties, and widths for width properties.

Comment: Oh wait, `em` and `ex` are heights, and `ch` is width. So the real answer here would be that you can use `ch` like `em` for setting widths.

Comment: (`ch` being a relatively new property that effectively didn't exist when the above was written in 2009.)

Answer (score 0):

Blixt's response is the correct one, but you can also do this if it makes the math easier:

```
font-family: Courier; 
font-size: 0.57em;
line-height: 1.2em;
width: 80em; 
height: 30em; /* 1.2 * 25; you could set the line-height at 1em and the box height at 25, 
                 but that would squish things too much */
```

Comment: Nope. That gives a box that 91x25 on my computer.