# Internet Explorer 11 "n" char based width doesn't fit "n" characters

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm building an app which requires a char ("ch") width components. But in IE11 it doesn't seems to be working.

For example:

```
<input style="width: 5ch; padding: 0; margin: 0; font-family: monospace" maxlength="5">
```

The width just don't fit 5 characters. Do anyone knows why? I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

---

[Plnkr example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zatO8iDFfn7tb8hn4qD4?p=preview)

---

Edited: I'm using monospace family fonts unlike the another question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 ch unit inconsistent between IE9+ and other browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825638/css3-ch-unit-inconsistent-between-ie9-and-other-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Better use [`size` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-size):

> The [`size`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-size) attribute gives the number of characters that, in a
>   visual rendering, the user agent is to allow the user to see while
>   editing the element's [value](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fe-value).

```css
input {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<input size="5" maxlength="5">
```

Comment: The problem with `size` is that it will not give you the correct width (as with `ch`)

Comment: Also I need to use with a div, the input was just an example.

Comment: On chrome `size=5` without the `maxlength` give the ability to set the value to `123456` and all chars fit inside.

Comment: @Dekel Well, that seems Chrome's fault. For some reason it makes the input one character wider than `size`.

Comment: @Oriol, check the rest of the definition: "If the attribute is present ... and if the result is a number greater than zero, then the user agent should ensure that **at least that many characters are visible**" - It's not the exact number.