# Length units ch vs em on IE

Tags: html, css

I have text with `font-family: monospace;` and `white-space: pre;` where I also want to set max-width to fit the text (so that the background colour does not go further to the right of the text than required).

The text is a maximum of 80 monospace characters wide, and so I set `max-width :82ch;`. This works exactly as expected on Firefox and Chrome, but on IE it doesn't play ball at all and wraps at around 60 characters. By inspection I appear to need to set `max-width: 95ch;` to have no wrapping on IE, but then that widens the display for Firefox and Chrome.

In researching this, I came across [The Lengths of CSS](https://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/) which states of the `ch` length unit:-

> **Notable browser support issues:** IE 9+, no Android default browser

to which I concur!

I tried using `em` as my length unit instead since, in a monospace font, my interpretation is that `em` and `ch` would be similar (if not the same).

From [Wikipedia: Em (typography)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)):-

> The name *em* was originally a reference to the width of the capital *M* in the typeface and size being used

My assumption is that the capital M is the same size as all the characters in a monospace font (that's the point of monospace) and so `em` and `ch` would be the same.

I also came across [CSS Units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) which has a table which shows support for `ch` only went in IE9, whereas support for `em` went in IE3, so I thought that might mean they had more chance to get it working!

What I found was that they were at least consistent, across all browsers, but that `max-width: 82em;` was WAAAY wider than my 80 monospace characters. By inspection I seem to need `max-width: 51em;` to make the correct fit.

I have inspected the "computed" values of `font-size` and `max-width` in the three major browsers and found them all to be identical. They all computed `font-size:13px;` and `max-width:663px;`. Since `max-width` is set to `51em` this makes `1em` = `13px;`

I don't understand why 80 characters in a monospace font don't take up 80 x 13px in width?

Is there some reason behind this that I have failed to understand or are the three major browsers who don't seem to be able to agree on anything, actually consistently doing something wrong?

**Question:** What is the correct way to set a width in a number of characters that will work **on all browsers**?

I fear that there may be no good answer to my question. I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255281/how-to-set-width-of-div-to-fit-constant-number-of-letters-in-monospace-font) which describes exactly what I want to do from back in 2009 and the answer (added more recently) is to use `ch`. Unfortunately `ch` doesn't work properly in IE, even at IE11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any solution that goes away from using the `ch` length unit ruins some perfectly good CSS for Firefox and Chrome just for the benefit of IE.

The following solution seems to be a good compromise as it works for IE10+ with some alternate CSS. IE9 is dropped from support by Microsoft so not going to lengths of supporting that too although it would be possible with conditional comments or other hacks.

```
.mybox {
    font-family:monospace;
    white-space:pre;
    max-width:82ch;
    width:82ch;
}
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    /* IE10+ CSS styles go here */
    .mybox {
        max-width:95ch;
        width:95ch;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`em` refers to the *em-square* of the font, `ch` to the *advance width* of the `0` character of the font. For any given font this will be a fixed ratio, but not typically = 1. For example, Courier New on Windows has a ratio of 1229/2048.

Note that when you specify the font-family as "monospace" different browsers on different operating systems will use different fonts for "monospace", which may have different advance width to em-square ratios.

Comment: So how do you use `em` to set the width as a number of characters?

Comment: I though `em` was the width of M in a font. Could you explain further what *em-square* means. Do you have a reference? Is there a way to discover the ratio to get the width to use?

Comment: The em-square isn't actually the size of anything. It defines a scale against which the other font metrics are set. When you say `font-size:16px`, that means that the em-square is 16px in size. The font and its glyphs have various metrics. ascent, descent, caps height x-height, advance width etc, which are each proportional to the em-square.

Comment: So if a font-size is set to, say, 13px - how many pixels wide would 80 characters be? My assumption was 80 times 13px. This doesn't appear to be the case though. What should the calculation be instead?

Comment: If the font was Courier New on Windows, it would be 80 * 13 * 1229 / 2048

Comment: How did you work that out though? What if it's some other monospace font? Is there some attribute that you can use to make the calculation?

Comment: Sadly no. The ratio is internal to the font file. You need to be able to inspect the font metrics of the font to know what the ratio is. I use [TypeLight 3.2](https://www.cr8software.net/typelight.html) for that.